# JSP Struts2 error that I cannot figure out on a basic Contact Manager app

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am trying to do the tutorial at [this website](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/01/tutorial-struts2-hibernate-example-eclipse.html) and I ran into this exception right at the point where I try to **ADD** a contact to the database by hitting the submit button.   I am looking for some advice on how to troubleshoot this?   I have to admit that I don't know anything about this opensymphony.xwork2 stuff.

```
No result defined for action my.contact.view.ContactAction and result input 
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:362)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:264)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:235)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:235)
```

If you want to download and try my code, here is the Eclipse project, all zipped up:
http://djangofan.blogsite.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/StrutsHibernate.7z

Comment: `struts.xml` inside classpath/`WEB-INF\classes`?

Comment: what action did u perform? add/Delete

Comment: i think u have given delete action

Comment: Please post the struts.xml mapping for your action and also your action code. This is usually caused by a conversion error which triggers the workflow interceptor to return "input" rather than the result you are expecting. Also, are you using any custom type converters?

Comment: I updated the question to contain a download if you want to load my project in Eclipse and try it, or if you want to see my actual code.

Answer (score 2):

As Steven has mentioned, if a validation or type conversion error occurs, `INPUT` gets returned if you're using the default interceptor stack, which would bypass your expected action code and look for the configured INPUT result.  So it could be a validation issue or it could be the entire app is misconfigured if you do have an INPUT result defined on the add action.

I skimmed the tutorial and would suggest starting fresh with one of the [Struts 2 Maven archetypes](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/struts-2-maven-archetypes.html) or using one of the [Struts 2 showcase](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C1953407438) projects as a starter instead.  In J2EE land you don't want to be manually managing your own jar versions & dependencies.  Also, the code in the tutorial has some issues, for example, the current Struts 2 documentation [explicitly states that action chaining isn't recommended](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/action-chaining.html) and that you should just use a simple redirect type instead.